# Documenting python script entry (__name__ == '__main__') using sphinx

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc

Is there a way, ideally using `autodoc`, to get sphinx to document a Python script?  The section of the script I want documented is the portion protected by:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
```

i.e. the bit that only runs if the module is used as a script instead of being imported.

Comment: I tried putting in a docstring just below the test.  I finally 'saw the light' and used the strategy below (function).

Answer (score 4):

You should extract the code in that block into a function, with a docstring, and call that function from the block.