# Include __main__.py in sphinx-apidoc generated files

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc, sphinx-apidoc

I am not able to add my __main__.py file correctly and its functions while generating RST file with **sphinx-apidoc**. Other files and classes are generated correctly.

I works only if I run sphinx-apidoc with `-P` parameter which includes private modules. But I do not want to add private methods of other modules, I need these from __main__.py only.

__main__.py looks like this:

```py
def main():
    """
    main() description here
    """
    f1()
    f2()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I would like to have `main()`, `f1()` and `f2()` included in RST files generated by sphinx-apidoc.

There is a similar question [Documenting python script entry (__name__ == '__main__') using sphinx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30780334/documenting-python-script-entry-name-main-using-sphinx) but it does not answer my question.

Comment: sphinx-apidoc ignores files starting with `_` (except `__init__.py`). See https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/blob/master/sphinx/ext/apidoc.py#L207. Do you need to have a `__main__.py` file ? Can you perhaps rename it?

Comment: @mzjn How would you automatically document the module then?

Comment: Create another RST file in which you add `.. automodule:: __main__`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is an undocumented feature, or a it can also be bug in `sphinx-apidoc` v.3.2.1. If we look at the [documentation for `-P` option](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/man/sphinx-apidoc.html#cmdoption-sphinx-apidoc-P), it reads:

> ```
> -P, --private
>     Include “_private” modules.
> ```

Notice this doesn't mention [`:private-members:` from autodoc flag options](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html#directives).

Two different issues are conflated, "private modules" and "private objects inside a module". The options that impact `.rst` file generation should be different for each according to the official documentation.

`sphinx-apidoc` will generate the `.rst` files based of 2 main templates, [`module.rst_t` and `package.rst_t`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/man/sphinx-apidoc.html#cmdoption-sphinx-apidoc-0). (Using Sphinx with a venv on *Windows* these are found under `/venv/Lib/site-packages/sphinx/templates/apidoc`).

The default behaviour (implemented by the templates) is to generate 1 `.rst` file per package, and within that file place 1 `.. automodule::` directive per module. What the `-P` option does (supposedly) is to add one more directive `.. automodule:: your-package.__private-module__` to the `.rst` file per private module.

An alternative is using `-e` option with `sphinx-apidoc` in which case a separate `.rst` file is generated for each module and package. So using `sphinx-apidoc -e -P` will cause an extra `.rst` file to be generated for private modules.

> But I do not want to add private methods of other modules

Private classes/methods/variables (objects inside a module) are impacted by the autodoc [`':private-members:'` option](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html#confval-autodoc_default_options).

`sphinx-apidoc` sets the default autodoc options of the generated `.. automodule::` directives as defined by the [`SPHINX_APIDOC_OPTIONS`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/man/sphinx-apidoc.html#environment) environment variable (namely, `:members:`, `:undoc-members:` and `show-inheritance`). These options can't be passed as a command line argument, you have to set the environment variable before running `sphinx-apidoc` to change the default values. (`sphinx-apidoc` does not take them from `conf.py`, unlike autodoc.)

Looking at the source code of `apidoc.py`

```py
# automodule options
if 'SPHINX_APIDOC_OPTIONS' in os.environ:
    OPTIONS = os.environ['SPHINX_APIDOC_OPTIONS'].split(',')
else:
    OPTIONS = [
        'members',
        'undoc-members',
        # 'inherited-members', # disabled because there's a bug in sphinx
        'show-inheritance',
    ]
```

Because `:private-members:` is a default autodoc options that should be set using `SPHINX_APIDOC_OPTIONS`  (as documentation states and source code shows). If you include the `-P` option, its only (documented) effect should be adding `.. automodule::` directives for private modules, what does happen is that it also sets the autodoc option `:private-members:` on each directive.

The following tree:

```
your_package
 ├  one_module.py
 ├  __init__.py
 └  __main__.py
```

With `sphinx-apidoc -P` will generate:

```
your_package.__main__ module
----------------------------

.. automodule:: your_package.__main__  <<-- -P option is documented as having this effect.
   :members:
   :undoc-members:
   :show-inheritance:
   :private-members:    <<-- -P option is not documented to have this effect.
```

So how to achieve the stated aim in the question?

If you use `-e` option with `sphinx-apidoc` generating one `.rst` file per module, you could use the `[EXCLUDE_PATTERN …]` from the signature. By running `sphinx-apidoc` twice, once for the `__main__.py` modules (together with `-P` option), and a second time for the remaining modules.

If you don't want individual `.rst` files for you modules, but instead the normal 1 `.rst` file for each package containing one directive per module. Then there is no practical possibility of achieving that (without resorting to considerable hacking). Your best choice is simply copy-pasting 1 `.. automodule::` directive per `__main__.py` into the `.rst` files after they are generated.