# How to make Sphinx autodoc extension include an underscore/private Python module

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc, sphinx-apidoc

I am autogenerating documentation for a Python package using Sphinx with the `autodoc` extension. The issue I am facing is that the `autodoc` skips any modules with an underscore.

Some modules were underscored to discourage users from importing them. However, the classes inside these underscored files have no underscores.

When I add the underscored module manually to the `package_name.rst` and ran `make html`, it shows. So my problem is how to automate that from `autodoc`.

I am trying to avoid parsing the `package_name.rst` via a script to add them. I am hoping for an autodoc flag or a hack!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's perhaps a misconception to think the `..automodule ::` directive applied to a package will automatically document sub-modules as members (by comparison with classes, variables, etc).

I just tested this but it can not be done using [`:private-members:` and or `:special-members:`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html#directive-automodule). Not by writing either option in the `.. automodule::` directive corresponding to the package. (Trying to set both options in [`autodoc_default_options`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html#confval-autodoc_default_options) gives the same result.)

The following example of package and module layout:

```
C:.
│ 
└────your_package
   │
   │   public_module.py
   │   _private_module.py
   │   __init__.py
```

Using a `.rst` with a single `.. automodule::` for the package:

```
Your package rst
================

.. automodule:: your_package
    :members:
    :undoc-members:
    :private-members:
    :special-members:
```

Minimal example `_private_module.py` with docstrings (`public_module.py` is the same except for the title):

```py
"""Private module docstring."""

class PublicClass:
    """Docstring."""
    pass
```

Does indeed give an empty documentation:

[image]

But if you remove the underscore from the module you get the exact same result.

> I am trying to avoid parsing the package_name.rst via a script to add them

If you are generating the `.rst` files with `sphinx-apidoc` if using the `-P` flag:

> [-P, --private](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/man/sphinx-apidoc.html#cmdoption-sphinx-apidoc-P)
>
> Include “_private” modules.
> New in version 1.2.

The generated files will include an `.. automodule::` directive for the private modules, this does have the side-effect of also including the `:private-members:` option as noted in another post [*"Include __main__.py in sphinx-apidoc generated files"*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54148095).

Example explicitly including the `.. automodule::` directives:

```
Your package rst
================

.. automodule:: your_package
    :members:
    :undoc-members:

    .. automodule:: your_package.public_module
        :members:
        :undoc-members:

    .. automodule:: your_package._private_module
        :members:
        :undoc-members:
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: It puts the private methods first. How do I make it put them last?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning the original problem in this question has since been fixed sometime in 2021, I can't locate the exact GitHub post but a several problems with `automodule` were fixed following [issue #7493](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/7493) was fixed. The question you ask in the comment is independent, member order doesn't have many options besides [`autodoc_member_order`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html#confval-autodoc_member_order)

Comment: @AlwaysLearning if using `groupwise` or `by-source` as options in the `automodule` or `autoclass` doesn't solve it for you you'll have to impose absolute order combining [`exclude-members`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html#confval-autodoc_default_flags) and [`private-members`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html#directive-option-automodule-private-members) and populating the lists or excluding [declaring them in the order you want](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html#directive-autofunction)

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I wrote [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71160147/10794031) that sums up the logic on ordering inside a directive.