# Insert an image and preserve the default order of members

Tags: python, image, python-sphinx, restructuredtext, autodoc

I want to have images after certain methods in Sphinx, what I have:

```
Foo
============

.. autoclass:: Bar.foo
    :exclude-members: baz

    .. automethod:: baz
    .. image:: ./images/baz_graph.png
```

The problem is that the order of methods gets mixed up and method `baz` is now the first one to appear even before `__init__` (default order is `bysource`).

What I want is to insert an image after a method and have that method and the image to go in the `bysource` order.

Comment: Would adding the image directive in the docstring of your method do what you want?

Comment: I am not sure, how do I do that? I am still new to this.

Comment: @StevePiercy (a note to VitaminC) putting [reST directives](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#directives) inside the docstring can be done and it would potentially help in taking advantage of the `bysource` automation, but the convention is to use the docstrings for arguments/return only (and some text comments). The `.rst` file itself works as a [presentation layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presentation_layer) so it's advisable to keep the presentation logic in the `.rst` file.

Comment: Sorry, @bad_coder, but I strongly disagree. Docstrings are intended to provide args and returns, as well as usage, examples, and anything else relevant to the object being documented. See [PEP 287](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0287/) and examples in Pyramid docstrings [rendered](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/api/authentication.html) and [source](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/_modules/pyramid/authentication.html#SessionAuthenticationHelper).

Comment: @StevePiercy I read some of the Pyramid documentation (unfortunately too late) and if I could go back at this point I would have followed many of the choices taken there (for example not relying on the napoleon extension to have one less dependency and source of bugs). But for example, the last section of PEP 287 also says you can put structural elements like headers in the docstring and unless I'm wrong Sphinx will throw an error if you do.

Comment: @StevePiercy Someone also objected that putting a lot of reST syntax inside the docstring would make things harder for devs who don't read reST (and after much struggling with Python and Sphinx quirks I take the choice of keeping everything as simple as possible -many of the projects I've seen follow that choice (including Sphinx itself)- as too make things easier for potential readers).  So I keep the docstrings simple for inline reading of the source and put most of the complexity in the `.rst` file (I think this can also simply things for users starting out with Sphinx).

Comment: @StevePiercy because if you are using autodoc, the docstring will be extracted and anything you write inside that directive in the `.rst` file is put underneath the extracted docstring. I've found this works best for me giving an optimal balance.

Comment: @StevePiercy that's not to mention the many standard library cases like Enum that just won't be well rendered by Sphinx and require manual rewriting (this was marked as "won't fix" by Sphinx devs) what happened was that if I started introducing the necessary workarounds in the docstrings after a while the docstrings were longer than the Python code itself...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to solve this like you want. Using any [`.. automethod::`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html#directive-automethod) directive inside an [`.. autoclass::`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html#directive-autoclass) directive (any directive declared for a member inside the containing outer directive) automatically places that declaration ahead of the remaining [automated order options](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html#confval-autodoc_member_order) for any of the ordering options and members `:member:`, `undoc-member`, `:private-members:`, etc...

You have to define order somehow, and the `:bysource:` option imposes one ordering; explicit directive declarations impose an additional ordering that supersedes the former. To order individual members you can mix the former two orderings, but if together the two orderings don't work like you want the only possible ordering that's left is the ordered declaration of directives in the `.rst` file for each member.

Of course it's convenient to explicitly declare as few members as possible and let the automated options fill in the remaining members... But if you also want to include an image beneath each member your only choice is declaring the inner directives explicitly with an [`.. image::`](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#image) directive.